# Too fast results in html containing javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

While working on the html code which contains some javascript code as well, i saw that the programm works but gives the results needed fast and then erases them in one single moment (I think that the problem is not rooted in the javascript code). What I need is to pause those results on screen, not erase them. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Geometric operations</title>
 <script>
      function Calculate(){
          var radius=document.forms["form1"]["radius"].value;
          if (radius==null || radius=="" || isNaN(radius)){
              alert("Please give the radius of the circle");
   return false;
   }
    var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById("radius").value,5);
    var perimeter = (2 * radius * Math.PI);
    var embadon = (radius * radius * Math.PI);

    document.getElementById("perimeter").value = perimeter;
    document.getElementById("embadon").value = embadon;
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculation of circle perimeter and circle area</h1>
To calculate the circle perimeter and circle area you need to give the radius and then press the button<b>"Calculation"</b><br>
<form name="form1" action="" method="" onSubmit="return Calculate()">
<pre>
Circle radius   : <input type="text" id="radius" size=5> m<br>
Circle perimeter  : <input type="text" id='perimeter' size=5> m <br>
Circle area   : <input type="text" id='embadon' size=5> m^2<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculation"   onclick="Calculate()">  
</pre></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or insight as to why this happens.

Comment: You are submitting your form when the submit button is pressed, which of course reloads the page. You need to prevent form submission in this case as well - or chose a more appropriate type of button in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe — That was my initial thought but it has `onSubmit="return Calculate()"` and `return false;` … oh, but that's in an if statement. The indentation is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @CBroe I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well do you think that i should replace the submit button whith something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run to send the form and execution of the function. The function is sent and the page is refreshed. Change the type of button `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and add `return false;`in the function.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Geometric operations</title>
 <script>
      function Calculate(){
          var radius=document.forms["form1"]["radius"].value;
          if (radius==null || radius=="" || isNaN(radius)){
              alert("Please give the radius of the circle");
   return false;
   }
    var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById("radius").value,5);
    var perimeter = (2 * radius * Math.PI);
    var embadon = (radius * radius * Math.PI);

    document.getElementById("perimeter").value = perimeter;
    document.getElementById("embadon").value = embadon;
    return false;
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculation of circle perimeter and circle area</h1>
To calculate the circle perimeter and circle area you need to give the radius and then press the button<b>"Calculation"</b><br>
<form name="form1" action="" method="" onSubmit="return Calculate()">
<pre>
Circle radius   : <input type="text" id="radius" size=5> m<br>
Circle perimeter  : <input type="text" id='perimeter' size=5> m <br>
Circle area   : <input type="text" id='embadon' size=5> m^2<br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Calculation"   onclick="Calculate()">  
</pre></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way if anyone wants the correct code,because the written one doesn't provide the right results here it is.

Comment: Please forgive my bad english as I had written before "far than useful" ,I meant more than useful. 
Thanks a lot! Rafal Mazgai,sorry for the misunderstanding of the person which sent the answer it was more than useful!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Geometric operations</title>
<script>
  function Calculate(){
      var radius=document.forms["form1"]["radius"].value;
      if (radius==null || radius=="" || isNaN(radius)){
          alert("Please give the radius of the circle");
return false;
}
var num=2;
var PI=3.14159;
var radius=document.forms["form1"]["radius"].value;
var perimeter = ((num) * (radius) * (PI));
var embadon = ((radius) * (radius) * (PI));

document.getElementById("perimeter").value = perimeter;
document.getElementById("embadon").value = embadon;
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculation of circle perimeter and circle area</h1>
To calculate the circle perimeter and circle area you need to give the 
radius and then press the button<b>"Calculation"</b><br>
<form name="form1" action="" method="" onSubmit="return Calculate()">
<pre>
Circle radius   : <input type="text" id="radius" size=5> m<br>
Circle perimeter  : <input type="text" id='perimeter' size=5> m <br>
Circle area   : <input type="text" id='embadon' size=5> m^2<br> 
<input type="button" name="SUBMIT" value="Calculation"onclick="Calculate()">  
 </pre></form>
 </body>
 </html>
```